# WordPress Admin Interface not styled properly

Tags: backup, localhost, local-installation, user-interface

The laptop I was working on recently crashed. But, I managed to get everything on it backed up, including my recent WordPress project off of my local server (I use MAMP).

I uploaded my SQL database and copied the WordPress website folder into my local server. The WordPress login interface looks normal, but after you get the login, it looks like this:

[image: error screenshot]

Is there something I missed when transferring my WordPress project from my old local server to the new one?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JohannesPille - Thank you very much for editing the post to make it much more understandable. Truly appreciated!

Comment: @brasofilo - And thank you very much as well for editing this post. Truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the wordpress URL and site URl are not set right.
Please try to edit your `wp-config.php` adding these lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Is your index on same folder as wp installation? if not, you need to place it there.

I'm talking about placing the URL in the above lines, not the index on the wp folder.

Comment: please note that if these lines are in your wp-config.php you wont be able to edit siteurl and wpurl by wp-admin panel, unless you delete them. but, if it works, you wont need to edit at admin panel, right? ;)

Comment: I declared those lines in my wp-config.php file and am still getting the same results when I log into my local WordPress administration interface. :(

Comment: Note, the URL I declared in the lines in your answer was: `http://localhost/portfolio`

Comment: After a few minutes, it reloaded and now my administrative interface is working properly. Thank you very much @user1576978

Comment: i'm happy to help, 'cause i've been helped many times :)